# how to program field collection output on drupal7

Tags: drupal-7

I quite new with drupal.

I work with drupal 7.

I create a content type with field collection that contain: name, birthdate, etc.

I would like to view on a block the next 3 birthday.

I need to check the value of the field and  print in in my way.

How can I do it? Is there a tutorial that explain it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [Views Module](https://drupal.org/project/views),

Step 1 : Create a views **Block** with your content-type.

Step 2 : Select the fields to be displayed on the Block (name,DOB, etc).

Step 3 : Do the **sort** for the field date (Day) greater than and equal to current date.

Step 4 : and limit the displaying content to 3 or any numbers you want.

If you are new to Drupal and learning views then follow this [series of tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3L9JLZOb_LQ)

Comment: For the birthday, I have the day&month and I need to calculate if the birthday accurate in the next days to show it. I tried to write a tpl but I dont know how to isolate the day&month values. I get all the fields in the field collection together as one block.